# White box over content (mobile view)

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a white box covering my content when viewing the website on a mobile phone not including tablets. It occurs once at the top under the first image slider, then again towards the bottom of the page... covering up a photo.

The website url is [designandcrate.com](http://www.designandcrate.com)

I have tried removing  tags and adding  tags so that the content will show up.

[span6]

[service_box title="Professional Staging with a Fresh Approach!!" subtitle=" With over 25 years of interior design experience in the residential and commercial world I am ready to focus on the area of staging! I recently renovated and staged a house in FL and loved the process and used new and older pieces to give a more realistic and fresh approach to the sometimes stagnant world of staging as a result!" icon="no" text="click "More" btn_text="See More" btn_link="#" btn_size="normal" target="_blank" custom_class="extra"]

[/span6]

I expected to see the content on my website, but can not see the content because of a white box covering the content.

ALSO a new discovery is that the issue could be a media query issue. Below is a photo of a string of code that could be related to what I am referring to.

[image of code relating to media query](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GHn6E.png)

Screenshot of mobile view
[Mobile view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/osBC8.jpg)
[mobileview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FMKeT.png)

**p.s. Sorry if I was not supposed to put a URL I am new to the forum...**

**UPDATE** I have found a temporary fix to show content... but it does not get rid of the box itself that is causing a big space with nothing in it...

Here is the link to a video of how I did this.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/q2ZnB.jpg

Comment: Can you also add a screenshot of what you are seeing on your mobile device

Comment: Added two pictures of white box on mobile view

Answer (score 0):

Try adding in your themes' custom CSS area the following:

```
.header:before {
    background: none !important;
}
```

Comment: Hold on could this be a media query issue....? I added to my post a photo for reference.

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved -- Thank you for the help.

> 

```css
.header .header_block {
 border-radius:2px
}
.camera_wrap {
 padding-top:30px;
 margin-bottom:-80px;
}
body.home .header:before {
 height:auto;
}
.clearfix {
 padding:10px;
}
```